# RxJS - Correct approach to do subscription for string value

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm completely beginner in RxJS, what I'm trying to do is some sort of pseudo-code in which I have initial string value, then after some time it will be changed by asynchronous request to server(in my code below I just used timeout function to change initial value after some time to imitate request to server).

How to correctly create Observer and subscribe to it in terms of this task? I wrote some code but really don't know whether it is correct approach or no, I would really appreciate if someone will review it and tell me the truth :) Also some other ways to achieve desired result will help me to understand what is going on here.

CodePen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grbaVw

```
var observableId = "11111111111";

var sourceAid = Rx.Observable.create(function (observer) {
    observer.onNext(observableId);
  });

var subscription = sourceAid.subscribe(
    function () {
              console.log("Initial value: " + observableId);
              setTimeout(function() {
                observableId = "22222222";
                console.log("New value from server: " + observableId);
        }, 2000);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The easy way: using Subjects

One way to resolve your issue is to use a Subject: a Subject in RXJS can be treated as an Observable; however, it also has an onNext method which allows us to push new data onto the observable sequence. We can perform the following:

```
var subject = new Rx.Subject();

var subscription = subject.subscribe(function (item) {
    console.log("Incoming item: " + item);
});

// We can push data immediately:
subject.onNext('First item');

// And at some later time, we can react to an asynchronous event as long
// as the event's callback has access to our subject:
setTimeout(function () {
    subject.onNext('NEW DATA');
}, 1000);

// The output of our program will be:
>> Incoming item: First item
>> Incoming item: NEW DATA
```

### The preferred approach: treating requests as observable streams

The preferred approach is to actually treat your asynchronous requests as a stream of data (WOW COOL!). In RXJS, promises can be treated as an observable sequence that will either emit a single item (the resolved data: a web response in your case) or a single error.

Let's pretend you're retrieving a friends list from the server: getFriendsList is a function that returns a Promise that resolves that data once it loads. We can do the following:

```
// Convert a web request Promise to a stream
var requestPromise = getFriendsList();
var response$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(requestPromise);

// Subscribe to the response$ stream
response$.subscribe(function (friends) {
   console.log('friends loaded:', friends);
});
```

And if you need to have an initial value, you can use the .startWith function to specify your initial data:

```
// Convert a web request Promise to a stream
var requestPromise = getFriendsList();
var response$ = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(requestPromise)
     // Start with an empty friend's list
     startWith([]);

// Subscribe to the response$ stream
response$.subscribe(function (friends) {
   console.log('friends loaded:', friends);
});
```